# One-pass algorithm (clarification needed) Why the space complexity is O(1)?

Tags: php, algorithm, profiling, big-o, qcachegrind

From [en.wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-pass_algorithm):

> A one-pass algorithm generally requires O(n) (see 'big O' notation) time **and less than O(n) storage (typically O(1))**, where n is the size of the input.

I made a test with xdebug.profiler_enable=1:

```php
function onePassAlgorithm(array $inputArray): int
{
    $size = count($inputArray);
    for ($countElements = 0; $countElements < $size; ++$countElements) {
    }

    return $countElements;
}

$range = range(1, 1_000_000);
$result = onePassAlgorithm($range);
```

The memory usage of this code in qcachegrind is: 33 558 608 bytes, and all 100% of them was used by the range() function.
And this part seems to me ok, because inside the onePassAlgorithm function we have only two int variables.
And that's the reason why *space complexity* is O(1).

Then I made another test:

```php
function onePassAlgorithm(array $inputArray, int $twoSum): array
{
    $seen_nums = [];
    foreach ($inputArray as $key => $num) {
        $complement = $twoSum - $num;
        if (isset($seen_nums[$complement])) {
            return [$seen_nums[$complement], $key];
        }
        $seen_nums[$num] = $key;
    }

    return [];
}

$range = range(1, 1_000_000);
$result = onePassAlgorithm($range, 1_999_999);
```

In qcachegrind we can see that onePassAlogorithm function uses only 376 bytes (the size of the return statement). Don't we need more to sequentially save in $seen_nums variable? So again *space complexity* is O(1)?

[image: result of the second code in qcachegrind]

My question is: Why qcachegrind shows that the variable $seen_nums in which we copy the entire $inputArray consumes no memory?

Or in other words why the storage complexity of my second realisation of this algorithm is O(1)?

Comment: Presumably the first one is faster because it doesn't do anything in the loop?

Comment: @greybeard it's $inputArray, renamed it.

Comment: Perhaps qcachegrind isn't telling you what you think it's telling you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Xdebug documentation:

[2007-05-17] — Removed support for Memory profiling as that didn't work properly.

[2015-02-22] — Xdebug 2.3.0
Added the time index and memory usage for **function returns** in normal tracefiles.

So the reason of my confusion was in that xdebug profiles shows only memory usage for **function returns**, and not the full memory profiling that i was expected.